# MongoDB push data to specific array element

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Hi guys so I'm doing meteor mongo db, I use findAndModify package

```
Ips.findAndModify({

      //Find the desired document based on specified criteria
      query: {
        "ipAdr": clientIp,
        connections: {
          $elemMatch: {
            connID: clientConnId
          }
        }
      },

      //Update only the elements of the array where the specified criteria matches
      update: {
        $push: {
          'connections': {
            vid: result.data.vid,
            firstName: result.data.properties.firstname.value,
            lastName: result.data.properties.lastname.value
        }
      }
    }); //Ips.findAndModify
```

So I find the element that I need however my info is being pushed to the whole connections array, but I want to push my info into that specific element. What should I do here? I tried

```
$push: {
              'connections.$': {
                vid: result.data.vid,
```

but it gives error.
Please help.

Comment: what error are you getting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the **$push** operator here as it adds a new element to array, instead you need to modify an element that is already in the array, try the **$set** operator to update as follows:

```
update: {
        $set: {
          'connections.$.vid': result.data.vid,
          'connections.$.firstName': result.data.properties.firstname.value,
          'connections.$.lastName': result.data.properties.lastname.value
        }
      }
```

Take into account that this way you will change only one element of the array that satisfies the condition from the **$elemMatch** statement.